# Posts & page twice display

Tags: themes

I install a fresh blog and add some posts & pages. With normal template/theme the pages and posts are fine while showing twice when i changed the theme.

The problem lies in the template but i don't have any idea, is there any problem in the loop or something else?

#### Additional Info:

Theme is Sahifa, a multi purpose magazine theme. If you need code sample of any file. i will show you.

Comment: I'd guess there is a custom query somewhere, or a bad filter, but without more information I don't think this is answerable. Please add as much information as you have available-- theme name, etc.

Comment: Sure! theme is Sahifa, a multi purpose magazine theme. If you need code sample of any file. i will show you.

Comment: That is a commercial theme, correct? You paid for it?

Comment: offcourse! Yes i have themeforest account

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't support commercial software as the source code is unavailable.

Comment: i will give you source code of that page you want, page.php or post.php

Answer (score 1):

I just figure out the problem, the problem lies in WPML plug-in. I consider the answer to be posted here for other users.

You have to put the following query in page.php or single.php to avoid duplicate/twice posts.

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```